# how to allow multiple selection of items in list view and show options like in whatsapp

Tags: android

If you use the whatsapp, you notice that you can do a long click on any message to select it. Then to select more messages, a normal click would suffice. Also at the top of the app, certain options become visible like copy, paste, share etc. On touching the back key, the selections are no longer highlighted.

It is very similar to the behaviour of selecting text in any android app, which happens automatically and does not require any kind of coding. Researching on this, I have been led to believe i need to use some combination of CheckedTextViews, selectors, onItemClickListeners etc. to achieve this behaviour.

So before i do attempt to implement this, I would like to ask if this kind of functionality is already available in the android framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Researching on this, I have been led to believe i need to use some combination of CheckedTextViews, selectors, onItemClickListeners etc. to achieve this behaviour.

That depends upon your implementation.

> I would like to ask if this kind of functionality is already available in the android framework?

Well, that depends upon your precise definition of "this kind of functionality".

Generally speaking, what you are seeing is [a contextual action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) (a.k.a., action mode). [Here are a series of apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode) demonstrating the use of a contextual action bar, including [one that supports using a long-press](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/LongPress) on a row to initiate the action mode.

Comment: The contextual action bar is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks! You have saved me a lot of experimenting.